# Potentially Ambiguous Stochastic Calculus Question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

In the Lecture Notes for my Stochastic Calculus module, my lecturer provides the following question as an essential exercise in preparation for the exam. It reads as follows:

> Let  $(W_t)_{t≥0}$ be a one-dimensional Wiener process. In the solution that you
> found in the previous exercise, replace $G_t$ by $W_t$, that is, set $X_t = xe^{at + bW_t}$. Write an equation for X.

Now, the previous exercise asked us to find a solution to the equation: $$d X_t = aX_t\, dt + bX_t \, dG_t, \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, X_0 = x,$$ where $G \in C^1$, i.e. $G$ is a continuously differentiable function and $G(0) = 0$, and  $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

My solution, as suggested in the original exercise was $$X_t = x e^{at + bG_t}$$

I'm not too sure what the process would be to answer the original question. It seems fairly ambiguous - am I essentially just reverse-engineering the 'previous exercise' and trying to find some sort of differential equation? If so, how would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question wants you to find a stochastic differential equation of the form $$dX_t = \mu (t,X_t) dt + \sigma (t, X_t) dW_t$$ for which $X_t = X_0 e^{at + b W_t}$ is a solution. You would approach this by applying Itô's formula on $X_t$. In particular, you should take $f(x,t) = e^{at + bx}$, find $f_x, f_t, f_{xx}$ and use Itô's formula to compute $df(t,W_t)$.

The reason why this is compared to the previous exercise is because when $G \in C^1$ you can formally substitute $dG = G^\prime (t) dt$. This is not something you can do for Brownian motion as its trajectories have unbounded variation.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. Could you perhaps extend your answer to include the first step of applying Ito's formula upon $X_t$? I am struggling to apply it

Comment: I've updated my answer with an extra hint.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that while $dG_t$ is of the scale $dt$, $dW_t\sim N(0,dt)$ is in $99\%$ of the cases of scale $\sqrt{dt}$. Thus while the higher powers of $dG_t$ are too small to contribute to the total, the square of $dW_t$ still is of size $dt$ and thus contributes.

$\newcommand{\D}{{\it\Delta}}\newcommand{\d}{\delta}$
Or to make that a little more exact, consider a time step $\D t$ with the increments $\D W_t=W_{t+\D t}-W_t$ etc. Then
$$
\D X_t=xe^{at+bW_t}(e^{a\D t+b\D W_t}-1)
$$
Using the exponential series this gives
$$
\D X_t=X_t\Bigl((a\D t+b\D W_t)+\tfrac12(a\D t+b\D W_t)^2+...\Bigr)
\\
=X_t\Bigl((a\D t+b\D W_t)+\tfrac12b^2(\D W_t)^2+O((\D t)^{3/2})\Bigr)
$$
To get a handle on how to treat the term $(\D W_t)^2$ consider an even smaller time step $\d t$ with $N\d t=\D t$. Then
$$
(\D W_t)^2=\left(\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\d W_{t+i\d t}\right)^2
=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}(\d W_{t+i\d t})^2+2\sum_{0\le i<j<N}\d W_{t+i\d t}\d W_{t+j\d t}
$$
Now by construction of the Wiener process, the $\d W_{t+i\d t}$ are independent and identically distributed $\sim N(0,\d t)$. By the law of large numbers,
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}(\d W_{t+i\d t})^2\approx N·\Bbb E[(\d W_{t})^2]=N·\d t=\D t
$$
and
$$
2\sum_{0\le i<j<N}\d W_{t+i\d t}\d W_{t+j\d t}\approx N(N-1)·\Bbb E[\d W_{t}\d W_{t+\d t}]=0
$$
so $(\D W_t)^2$ can be replaces with $\D t$, the deviations from that cancel out over larger time intervals.